# Unify timestamps as date strings

Tags: matlab, datetime, matlab-table

MATLAB R2015b

I have a table containing a date string and a time string in various formats in two columns for each row:

```
11.01.2016 | 00:00:00 | data

10/19/16 | 05:29:00 | data

12.02.16 | 06:40 | data
```

I want to convert this two columns to one column with a common format:

```
31.12.2017 14:00:00
```

My current solution uses a loop over each row and combines the columns as strings, checks for the various formats to use datetime with an appropriate format string and then uses datestr with the desired format string. Datetime was not able to automatically determine the format of the input string.

As you can imagine, this is horribly slow for large tables (approx. 50000 rows).

Is there any faster solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a try to vectorize the code. The trick is to

1. convert tables > cell > char-array, then
2. manipulate char strings, then
3. convert back from char-array > cell > table

Also, there is an important bit to pad all cells having shorter lenths with 'null' character in a vectorized way. Without this, it will not be possible to convert from cell > char-array. Here is the code.
clc
    clear all

```
%% create Table T
d={'11.01.2016';
   '10/19/16';
   '12.02.16'};

t={'00:00:00';
  '05:29:00';
  '06:40'};
dat=[123;
    456;
    789];

T = table(d,t,dat);

%% deal with dates in Table T
% separate date column and convert to cell
dd = table2cell(T(:,1));
% equalize the lengths of all elements of cell
% by padding 'null' in end of shorter dates
nmax=max(cellfun(@numel,dd));
func = @(x) [x,zeros(1,nmax-numel(x))];
temp1 = cellfun(func,dd,'UniformOutput',false);
% convert to array for vectorized manipulation of char strings
ddd=cell2mat(temp1);
% replace the separators in 3rd and 6th location with '.' (period)
ddd(:,[3 6]) = repmat(['.' '.'], length(dd),1);
% find indexes of shorter dates 
short_year_idx = find(uint16(ddd(:,nmax)) == 0);
% find the year value for those short_year cases
yy = ddd(short_year_idx,[7 8]);
% replace null chars with '20XX' string in desirted place
ddd(short_year_idx,7:nmax) = ...
    [repmat('20',size(short_year_idx,1),1) yy];
% convert char array back to cell and replace in table
dddd = mat2cell(ddd,ones(1,size(d,1)),nmax);
T(:,1) = table(dddd);

%% deal with times in Table T
% separate time column and convert to cell
tt = table2cell(T(:,2));
% equalize the lengths of all elements of cell
% by padding 'null' in end of shorter times
nmax=max(cellfun(@numel,tt));
func = @(x) [x,zeros(1,nmax-numel(x))];
temp1 = cellfun(func,tt,'UniformOutput',false);
% convert to array for vectorized manipulation of char strings
ttt=cell2mat(temp1);
% find indexes of shorter times (assuming only ':00' in end is missing
short_time_idx = find(uint16(ttt(:,nmax)) == 0);% dirty hack, as null=0 in ascii
% replace null chars with ':00' string
ttt(short_time_idx,[6 7 8]) = repmat(':00',size(short_time_idx,1),1);
% convert char array back to cell and replace in table
tttt = mat2cell(ttt,ones(1,size(t,1)),nmax);
T(:,2) = table(tttt);
```

Comment: However I had to make some adjustments to fit it to mHowever I had to make some adjustments to fit it to my needs:

Find american date format and switch month and day
usDates = ddd(:,3) == '/';
ddd(usDates, [1 2 4 5]) = ddd(usDates, [4 5 1 2]);

I had to set nmax to 10 and 8 repectively. The proposed calculation failed, when only two-digit years or only non-second-displayed elements were present.

I removed the calls to find because logical indexing is a little bit faster.

Combining the two char arrays in one:
tttt = mat2cell(tttt,ones(1,size(raw,1)),nmaxTimes+nmaxDates+1);

Comment: yes, it can be customized. From the example you had given, I just showed how to tranform data from table to an array structure (which is more easily vectorizable).

Answer (score 0):

If you call the two columns cell arrays `c1` and `c2`, then something like this should work:

```
c = detestr(datenum(strcat(c1,{' '},c2)), 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```

Then you would need to drop the old columns and put this one `c` in their place.  On the inside, `datenum` must be doing something similar to what you're doing, however, so I'm not sure if this will be faster. I suspect that it is because (we can hope) the standard functions are optimized.

If your table isn't representing those as cell arrays, then you may need to do a pre-processing step to form the cell arrays for `strcat`.

Comment: Sadly datenum was not able to distinguish the different date formats :-/

Comment: You may not need the `datenum` call in the middle - It might be enough to call `detestr` on a string, but I doubt that will be better for distinguishing. How many date formats do you have? The ones in your example seemed recognizable enough. In the example, it looks like incoming dates are "American style" with month preceding day, and the output is clearly "European style" with the day preceding month. Is that generally true? Maybe try converting all of the input '.' to '/'?  The dot format is not standard in the US and looks like it might have less support in Matlab by default. @user2760995